# Alternative to URLDownloadToFile function

Tags: c++, winapi, https, httpclient, wininet

Are there any alternative to the `URLDownloadToFile` function? I cannot download anything from an **HTTPS** server with invalid certificate. Are there any generic HTTP clients which I can use to download a file from an HTTPS server with an invalid certificate? Are there any other alternatives for this situation? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl), a easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library.

[Here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) talks about how to deal with ssl cert with it.

Comment: I ended up doing it like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/314167/Alternative-to-URLDownloadToFile-function

Answer (score 2):

Try using CInternetSession::OpenURL. I'm not sure if it helps with your problem with invalid certificates, but you were asking for alternatives to URLDownloadToFile.

```
    CInternetSession connection;
    CStdioFile* stream = connection.OpenURL("https://www.google.com");

    const int capacity = 10000;
    char* buffer = new char[capacity];
    int bytes_read = stream->Read(buffer, capacity);

    FILE* output = fopen("C:\\output.html", "w");
    fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, output);
    fclose(output);
```